# How can i acctually get to uploading python projects on public internet?

Tags: python, server, upload, project, pythonanywhere

How is websites like pythonanywhere developed?
Are there any other ways to upload python projects on servers publicly?
I want to know if there is a way to straightly create servers and stuff.
Thanks.

I tried pythonanywhere but it didnt work out as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I am taking it correct, you want to showcase your projects to the community publically. What I saw in the website is it is a type of online compiler. Means you can only run your code there.
For showing it publically there are many other websites such as the most popular
[Github](https://github.com/)

Comment: thanks for answering. however,  I want to know how to upload webapplication without using other website services. Are there ways for this?

Comment: sorry for understanding it wrong. I do not much about hosting. Hope you find your answers soon :)